# How to split a dataframe based on column values, sort or groupby for string values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Completely new to coding and pandas.

```
df

   Date         Particulars    Inwards  Code

1 2017-04-01         EFG           12800    01
2 2017-07-22         ABC           100      01
3 2017-09-05         BCD           10000    01
4 2018-03-13         ABC           2000     01
```

I wanted to output 3 dataframes from this `df` based on the `df['Particulars']` column, i.e.

Output:
   df1

```
   Date         Particulars    Inwards  Code

2 2017-07-22         ABC           100      01
4 2018-03-13         ABC           2000     01
```

df2

```
   Date         Particulars    Inwards  Code

1 2017-04-01         EFG           12800    01
```

df3

```
   Date         Particulars    Inwards  Code

3 2017-09-05         BCD           10000    01
```

I have a way of doing it through:

```
 df1 = df1.append(df.loc[df['Particulars'] == 'ABC'], ignore_index=False)
```

while I initialise a list of `Particulars` and make dataframes and then do the above command using a `for loop`. But I am wondering if `sort` or `groupby` would be better options? And how exactly to apply them I tried `groupby` and `sort` but can't get the dataframe.

Comment: In this case you can just do: `df1 = df[df['Particulars'] == 'ABC']` and so on.

Comment: @pault I am trying to avoid making a list of the unique items in 'Particulars' as its a 1000 row df and then setting up empty dataframes in the list(making a dictionary) and then looping through. :( I was hoping there was a way to split the dataframe based 'Particulars' column

Comment: `[y for x ,y in df.groupby('Particulars')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of data frames by grouping your df on Particulars.

```
d = {index: label for index, label in df.groupby('Particulars')}
```

Now you can access each df using

```
d['ABC']

    Date        Particulars Inwards Code
2   2017-07-22  ABC         100     1
4   2018-03-13  ABC         2000    1
```

Comment: Nice, I forgot about this one. One question, though. Does calling `groupby` automatically mean it's O(n log n) as in the background it creates groups by sorting? I seem to remember this was the case.

Comment: @jpp, the complexity of loop including LC is O(n), not sure whether grouping impacts it further. Time to dog further :)

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary comprehension is the cleanest way to structure your data:

```
d = {k: df[df['Particulars'] == k] for k in df['Particulars'].unique()}
```

Related: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)